# What does the FlaskForm does and how does it work under the hood?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I am new to `Flask` and I found `flask_wtf` package and read a documentation of it and saw some videos related to the package.

However, there is no mention of what `FlaskForm` does when other classes inherit from it. What does this do under the hood and what does it contain inside of it.

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

What is the responsibility of FlaskForm inside brackets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the [FlaskForm API](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.x/api/#flask_wtf.FlaskForm) ?

It's a subclass of Form, have you read [Form API](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form) ?

If you wish to know what's going on under the hood further than the doc, then you need to read the [code](https://github.com/wtforms/flask-wtf/blob/main/src/flask_wtf/form.py#L27) :)